# How to use php in html coding to reduce no. Of .html files?

Tags: php, html

I have made the structure of a website. I have made three .html files named index.html, blog.html, posts.html. index.html is the home page and on that page their is a link for blog.html on the blog.html page thier are some posts heading and i have connected one post to posts.html. But now i'm in trouble that if i have to made one .html file for each post then it would be very difficult so what should i do so that i have to make only one posts.html and anyhow connect it to a php file or something else so that i don't have to make many .html file for every post. 
Can i use php for it, is their any command that--> if you click on this post then this page will open and if you click on another post then another page will open. By this i will give the command for all the posts and  it will help me alot.

Thank you

Comment: other way around. you don't put php into an html file. you put html into a php file, and then that php code generates the contents of your individual pages, using that one single script.

Comment: php with sql databases

Comment: Okay, but how can i do it? Can tell me the code for it? Or something else which can help me like a function of php which is designed for this purpose?

Comment: Not clear question. No personal research. Has not read site guidelines for asking good questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try file_get_contents php, or create a small ajax client to load html.

$your_html_file = file_get_contents('./test.html', FILE_USE_INCLUDE_PATH);